# How to convert a function from vbscripts to javascript

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I have a vbscript function which I need to covert to javascript function. The function uses eval() and it has been quite confusing for me to covert that part to javascript

There is a need to rewrite this as the current function is not working on chrome browser.

I only need help with this part of the code

```vb
     locParts = ""
        locAisle = RTrim(LTrim(eval("document.all.bbaisle" & x & ".value"))) & ""
        locBay = RTrim(LTrim(eval("document.all.bbbay" & x & ".value"))) & ""
        locLevel = RTrim(LTrim(eval("document.all.bblevel" & x & ".value"))) & ""
        locBin = RTrim(LTrim(eval("document.all.bbbin" & x & ".value"))) & ""

Function buildLocation(x)

    test = eval("document.all.bbtype" & x & ".value") & ""

    if test = "A" then

    ' This is a multipart location that needs to be assembled prior to validation back in calling procedure
    locParts = ""
    locAisle = RTrim(LTrim(eval("document.all.bbaisle" & x & ".value"))) & ""
    locBay = RTrim(LTrim(eval("document.all.bbbay" & x & ".value"))) & ""
    locLevel = RTrim(LTrim(eval("document.all.bblevel" & x & ".value"))) & ""
    locBin = RTrim(LTrim(eval("document.all.bbbin" & x & ".value"))) & ""

    if locAisle <> "" then
        locParts = locParts & locAisle & "_"
    end if

    if locBay <> "" then
        locParts = locParts & locBay & "_"
    end if

    if locLevel <> "" then
        locParts = locParts & locLevel 
    end if

    if locBin <> "" then
        locParts = locParts & "_" & locBin
    end if

    if locParts <> "" then
        Execute("document.all.bb" & x & ".value=" & CHR(34) & UCASE(locParts) 
        & CHR(34))
    end if

    buildLocation = 1

else

    ' This is either an existing KT location or Offsite so do nothing
    buildLocation = 1

end if    

End Function
```

this is what I come up with in javascripts but i doubt this will work if I duplicate it for other variables.

```
locParts = ""
locAisle = eval("document.getElementById('bbaisle')"+ x +".value").trim()
```

Comment: `eval("document.all.bbaisle" & x & ".value")` is a really really shitty way of doing `document.getElementById('bbaisle'+x).value`.

Comment: How this is translated to modern JS depends on whether `bbaisleXXX` etc. are `name`d or `id`d that.

Comment: @AKX bbaislexxx is and id

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I must say this is not my code and I agreed that its quite shitty does the need for me to convert it and get it right. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could work for you, but it's hard to test without the HTML markup.

```
function getField(name) {
  return document.getElementById(name) || document.getElementsByName(name)[0];
}

function getTrimmedFieldValue(name) {
  const field = getField(name);
  return (field ? field.value : "").trim();
}

function buildLocation(x) {
  const type = getTrimmedFieldValue("bbtype" + x);
  if (type === "A") {
    const locAisle = getTrimmedFieldValue("bbaisle" + x);
    const locBay = getTrimmedFieldValue("bbbay" + x);
    const locLevel = getTrimmedFieldValue("bblevel" + x);
    const locBin = getTrimmedFieldValue("bbbin" + x);
    const bbValue =
      (locAisle.length ? locAisle + "_" : "") +
      (locBay.length ? locBay + "_" : "") +
      locLevel +
      (locBin.length ? "_" + locBin : "");
    const targetField = getField("bb" + x);
    if (targetField) {
      targetField.value = bbValue.toUpperCase();
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```